# How can I use Rhino mocks to mock just one value in a test object?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Been making some changes to our code, and now I need to re-factor some unit tests to make sure they're compatible with the new code. I've come up against a problem. In this:

```
            ChannelLoad loader = new ChannelLoad(_customerDbMock, _bulkCopyMock);
            loader.Execute(taskId);
```

The "loader" object is now trying to connect to another object in order to get a string value whereas before the string was returned automatically. So the obvious solution is to mock that object to return a suitable value for the test. However for various reasons I can't easily do this.

Ideally what I'd like to be able to do is to get a "real" (i.e as specified in code) loader object that performs a "real" Execute method but which has a "mock" value for that particular string. But I'm really not sure how to do this - even if it's possible - with Rhino Mocks. The string property in question isn't abstract or anything - it's protected and it's actually read-only. This is how it looks inside "loader":

```
    protected string DbConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return _Service.GetLocalDatabase().GetConnectionString(_Service);
        }
    }
```

And the problem is that for the test environment "GetLocalDatabase" returns nothing.

Anyone help me out here? Is there a way I can mock this up using Rhino Mocks or is my only option to refactor the code to make it not rely on an external object? If the latter, pointers would also be helpful.

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two other options if you don't want to inject _Service:

Create a class that inherits from ChannelLoad (call it "TestableChannelLoader" or something) and

1. overwrite the DbConnectionString-Property or
2. extract a method "GetConnectionString" that you can override in your new class and call it in the DbConnectionString-Property

Answer (score 2):

I see that loader has dependency to _Service. So, you need to inject mock of this dependency to loader in order to change DbConnectionString property behavior.

Comment: I can't do that without major refactoring - is that really the only option?

Comment: Are you writing tests to legacy code? And, BTW are you testing loader, or some other object?

Comment: Yes, I'm testing loader. And it's sort of legacy code: I've made changes to the code base and now I'm going through the unit tests and changing them as required to make sure they're testing what they should be, and passing. This particular one is erroring because it's calling an external object which - in the test environment - doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't think mocking properties of object under test is a good idea. How reference to _Service passed to loader?

Comment: Yeah, this is the problem. Someone who came before me on this unfortunately made this suite of tests dependent on an Integration Test helper object - that's what's generating the reference to _Service. That's obviously bad architecture and the more I think about it the more it seems that refactoring to remove that dependency - and replace it with a mock - is the only sensible option. It's just that as usual I'm up against time and was hoping for a faster solution. But you've made me see sense, so have a tick :)